# What exactly is "pinning" in relation to indexes?

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, rdbms

When one talks about "pinning" in indexes, what exactly is this? Is there some other word/term I can search for, as google has not provided any solutions.

It is part of a test question, where students were asked to define and describe pinning in relation to indexes.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

"pinning" in Oracle parlance basically means "ensure that this is always kept in memory".

It is frequently used for hot indexes that see a lot of queries against them, but might ordinarily age out of Oracle's cache (and thus have to be re-read from the disk).  By pinning the index in memory the index scan will theoretically never require a disk access.  If the index is large and the cache cycles frequently this could be a substantial performance improvement over frequently refreshing the cache.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Do you think you could link some sort of explanation as I need to read about it in detail. Or is there possibly another word for it?